# Moving Project under TFS Source Control to New Development Machine

Tags: tfs

I have moved to a new development machine, and I need to re-establish TFS binding for all of my current Visual Studio projects, which I have copied to the new machine.

When I try unbinding and rebinding my projects to TFS, the status remains at Invalid.

The only success that I've had in getting the projects on my new machine bound to TFS again is to unbind them, and then re-add the projects to source control. Then TFS makes you resolve "conflicts" between the server and your local copy for every file in each of your projects.

Although this works, it is an inefficient process. Is there a better, prescribed way of doing this.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Just map a new workspace and grab the files from source control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot simply copy the workspace folder to new development machine, it cannot identify the copied folder as workspace. Even if you binding and rebinding, you still need to add the local files to source control again to identify them.

Daniel is right. Just checkin the changes from the old development machine to TFS, then map a new workspace on your new development machine and get the files from source control.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Daniel and Andy.

I thought that I could just bring copies of my working folders over to the new machine and everything would be wonderful. Obviously, that was not a good idea.

Finally seeing the error of my ways, I cleared out all my copies, removed the Workspaces and deleted the Workspace folders under Users/me/Source/Workspaces, and remapped everything, and let TFS download the files--which took much less time than what I had wasted.

I hope this helps somebody from not making the same mistake.